# Finding value of 'i' in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, pre-increment

I have this question here:

> What is i after the following for loop?
>   The given code is:

```
 int y= 0; 
for (int i= 0; i<10; ++i) 
{  
  y+= i; 
}
```

I put that the answer is 9, but that is incorrect according to the grader. I even printed 'i' and it came out as 9.

Comment: `i` doesn't exist after the for-loop because it goes out of scope.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the value of y? Because that certainly won't be 9...

Comment: The last value of i before it cease to exist is 10. That is the value that makes the loop break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `i` would be 10. As of now, if you try to print the value of `i` outside the loop, `i` is undefined.

When `i` was 9, you continued with the loop, for next iteration `i` became 10 and condition fails and causes to break the loop. So value of `i` is 10. Keep it in mind having stpe statement as `++i` or `i++` is not different w.r.t the values that `i` would attend. step statement always executes before start of the next iteration.

Following small change would help you to prove the output.

```
 int i,y= 0; 
 for (i= 0; i<10; ++i) 
 {  
      y+= i; 
 }
 printf("%d\n",i);
```

That being said if you are printing the value of `i` within the loop, then you'll get maximum value of `i` as 9 on the output. Probably this is what you were doing to conclude the answer as 9.

```
 int y= 0; 
 for (int i= 0; i<10; ++i) 
 {  
     y+= i; 
     printf("%d\n",i);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you that is exactly what I was doing. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that i is undefined after the loop. It is 9 at the last iteration, though.

Comment: `i` is 10 at the last iteration, but everything else is spot on.

Comment: Guess it depends on how we define "last iteration". If we were to print the value of `i`  inside the loop the highest value you'd see is 9, but `i` is assigned the value 10 before the program exits the loop. I think. Now I have to go try it.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Using `y+=i` is constantly adding the current value of `y` to the value of `i`. So, in turn, you're not getting the true value of `i`, but rather the cumulative value.

This is what is actually happening in `y+=i`

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
```

Also, just printing out `i` after the loop would be invalid since outside that for loop, `i` no longer exists.

You could just do this:

```
int y=0;
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
  y=i;
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: `y+=i` is `y= y + i`, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, `y+=i` is basically `y` constantly adding itself to `i`